# How to apply different formats to different columns or cells Webdatarocksja

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webdatarocks

Hello I need to apply different formats to my dataset depending on the column is in is this possible to do with web data rocks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking on "Format -> Format cell" and "Format -> Conditional formatting". They can be applied to different columns and cells. The best part is that they can be saved to config for either restoring or reusing in the future.

Just press "Save" to save the current pivot's state.

The "Conditional formatting" is saved as "conditions" and the "Format cells" is saved as "formats".

Also, here are some references to the official documentation: https://www.webdatarocks.com/doc/conditional-formatting/, https://www.webdatarocks.com/doc/number-formatting/

Comment: How do I apply a specific format to a column?, I have been trying to do it does it depend on the name given?

Comment: You can apply a specific format to a column through the UI tools: 1. open config popup 2. choose the column name you need to format 3. choose configs. 4. press "Apply". If you want to do it with code please see format object sample: { "name": "currency", "decimalPlaces": 2, "currencySymbol": "$"} then apply it to measure in slice: {"uniqueName": "Price", "format": "currency"}.